# manage users in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to manage the position/order of each user logged in my app.
I made an array that is updated every time that someone enters.
until now, it's working fine.

```
[...]
var row_of_users=[];//my array of users.
var visits=0;//just a count of users logged in.

io.on('connection', function(socket){
var user=socket.id;
visits++;
row_of_users.push(user);
console.log(row_of_users);
[...]
```

**in the console.log shows:**

*[ 'BnUtfcyNniEWNwN3AAAA',
  'IkE3l4oMBXt5dEsOAAAB',
  't5gzbSru7oDR44T7AAAC',
  'yB2X4G55YqcvDgHcAAAD' ]*

but when an user leaves, socket.io ignores the user.id and deletes the last object in the array.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
visits--;
row_of_users.pop(user);
});
```

**if i close THE FIRST user tab in my browser (**BnUtfcyNniEWNwN3AAAA**) in the console.log now shows this:**

[ 'BnUtfcyNniEWNwN3AAAA',
  'IkE3l4oMBXt5dEsOAAAB',
  't5gzbSru7oDR44T7AAAC' ]

like if the last user disconnected.

What's happening here? and how can i update the array correctly?
I didn't post the entire code cuz my language is portuguese and the variables are in portuguese too.

Comment: Where are you placing the disconnect listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array.pop()` doesn't take any arguments and will always pop the last element.

*[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)*

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element.

To remove the Nth element use:

`array.splice(N, 1)`

Or in your case:

`row_of_users.splice(row_of_users.indexOf(user), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies here: [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Basically, you'll use indexOf(socket.id) and splice that index from the row_of_users array.